# Unfortunate resolution change. Xrandr refuses to switch

Tags: nvidia, display, resolution, xrandr

So unfortunately, just recently having installing Kubuntu 15.04, I wanted to get the resolution to fit my TV. The starting res of 1024x768 was too small for me. Having installed the NVIDIA drivers for my GTX 760, I messed around in the GUI menu (found out that my TV is so old, not even LCD or LED) that it only went up to 1366x768. I didn't like it that far, So I switched downwards to 1152x768 and realized that my TV didn't support the res. I set the res, and Now I can't see anything except the TV's error "Invalid Mode" So I opened the tty and tried numerous commands using Xrandr after a lengthy research about the topic. I tried multiple different codes:

```
Xrandr -s 1024-768 
Xrandr --output DVI-I-0 --(something)
```

I was experiencing the error "Can't open display's" But I fixed that after research. I tried all this and it was still stuck at the same res. I most constantly get this:

```
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  7 (RRSetScreenSize)
  Serial number of failed request:  33
  Current serial number in output stream:  34
```

If anyone has any thoughts, that would be much appreciated, I don't want to reinstall.

Comment: Did you try renaming the /etc/X11/xorg.conf file?  Using the defaults might help.

Comment: How do I do that from the command line? I forgot to mention in the original post, That I am not that well versed in how to do things. I'll be able to understand mumble jumble, but I won't know how to do it.

Comment: sudo   mv   /etc/X11/xorg.conf    /etc/X11/xorg.conf.save      
Then startx or reboot

Comment: It's telling me "No such file or directory" in both my attempts using cd and not using cd.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my issue! After trying the commands you suggested to me (thanks by the way) I tried the command

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

which backed up the existing xorg and created a new one, and I used startx to boot back up and it worked fine (albeit at 640x480)

Thanks again